# POSTMAN Transactional Messaging API Create SMS "content" section: How do you put Ampscript in/double single quotes does not work

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, postman

In creating a Transactional Messaging API SMS definition, putting block of AMPscript with " isn't working with **Postman**.

```json
{
  "definitionKey": "CentricTransSMS2",
  "name": "CentricTransSMS2",
  "description": "Using new SMS Transactional API",
  "content": {
    "message": "
%%[

var @language , @passcode

set @language = AttributeValue("locale")
set @passcode = AttributeValue("code")

IF @language == "es" then
Set @msg = Concat("SPANISH text: Your authentication code is ",@passcode,".")

else

Set @msg = Concat("ENGLISH : Your SETF authentication code is ",@passcode,".")

endif ]%%

%%=v(@msg)=%% 

"

  },
  "subscriptions": {
    "shortCode": "XXXXX",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "keyword": "join"
  }
}
```

The double quotes in the AMPscript seem to close the beginning double quote and I've tried all combinations of quotes and double quotes, etc.

Comment: Did you try escaping the double quotes with a backslash, as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637429/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-json)?

Answer (score 0):

As Lukas Lunow said, you need to escape the double quotes with backslashes.

Here's an example:

```
"Add_ons": "{
                   \"Transfer\": [
                     { \"add_on_name\": \"Mercedes S450\", \"add_on_count\": \"1\", \"add_on_price\": \"30.39\", \"add_on_description\": \"this is a description\" }
                 ]}"
```

Alternatively, you can use a Chrome Extension called "SFMC Transactional API GUI" (found here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sfmc-transactional-api-gu/hgnpnninmcjjnigajajkajhocoegfckk?hl=en) to create send definitions through a user interface. However, please note that this is not an official tool from Salesforce.